# How to solve equations with Casio FX-85WA calculator

Tags: calculator

I am testing the casio FX-85WA calculator to solve equations, so I am trying to solve a very simple one: $2x-1=3$. But I am unable to input the equal sign, as it puts the result. I've seen others calculators have the `calc` or `solve` button, but this calculator doesn't have it. So I'm unsure if this calculator can solve equations or not, I checked the manual but doesn't have any examples for equations.

Here is a picture of the calculator:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going swiftly through the calculators's Manual I found this section which explains the only use of the $X\ \& \ Y$ buttons:

[image]

Hence the confirmation of what you suspected: this calculator does not solve any equations

Answer (score 0):

Sir, according to the image, and the instructions, you should be able to solve a quadratic or linear equation. The fx-85wa model has the "Alpha" key which is exactly the key needed on a certain Casio models to correctly input equations.

Can you tell me what happens when you follow the above instructions?

/Silicon Valley Regards

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to calculate. You have a model: Casio fx-85WA, not a Casio fx-85W. There is no CALC button.